# Vue/Quasar: how to add a persitent query param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

Given an app on Vue 3 and Quasar 2.6.
I'm trying to add a param into the url so it would persist during navigation. The idea is that it's used on application start to initialize an app state and then is kept in the url. On state changing the param is updated.
I searched through questions here and it looks like I should use router's `beforeEach` hook. The problem is that I'm getting "Infinite redirect in navigation guard" error.

router/routes.ts:

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: MainLayout,
    props: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: IndexPage,
      },
      {
        path: 'configuration',
        component: ConfigurationPage,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

router/index.ts:

```
import routes from './routes';

export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : (process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history' ? createWebHistory : createWebHashHistory);

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,
    history: createHistory(process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE),
  });

  return Router;
});
```

App.vue:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  created: async () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      let toWithQuery = Object.assign({}, to, { query: from.query });
      next(toWithQuery);
    });
  }
});
```

[UPDATE] I also tried the suggested by @yoduh approach:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  if (!Object.keys(to.query).length) {
    return Object.assign({}, to, { query: from.query })
  }
})
```

but it causes indefinite recursion when I do `router.push({ path: '/configuration' })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return anything other than `next()` from a navigation guard you are invalidating the current navigation and causing a new navigation to be performed. Any *new* navigation needs to pass **all** navigation guards. `next(toWithQuery)` is always triggering a new navigation which causes `router.beforeEach` to always run again, repeating infinitely.

I would suggest removing the `next` parameter.  It's [not recommended](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#Optional-third-argument-next) anymore.

When the navigation is valid, you don't actually need to return anything

> If nothing, `undefined` or `true` is returned, the navigation is validated, and the next navigation guard is called.

An example of a working version of your beforeEach guard would be:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  if (!Object.keys(to.query).length && Object.keys(from.query).length > 0) {
    return Object.assign({}, to, { query: from.query })
  }
})
```

This code adds a query to the `to` route only if the `to` route has no query params and the `from` route does.  Otherwise, the navigation is validated. This guard should only run at most two times (once to add the query, once to successfully validate)

Comment: Hi, @yoduh, thanks for you answer. It almost works. Or I'd say it works during normal navigation by clicking router links. But I have some code in App.vue's created hook that fetches server and redirects (via `router.push({ path: '/configuration' })`) to a route in a case of server exception (app isn't initialized). And in that case the hook you provided is being called indefinitely

Comment: Try my updated answer.  It will check to make sure the `from` route has query parameters before adding them.